# Javascript atob is not decoding the base64 string properly

Tags: javascript, html, string, base64

I'm trying to decode a javascript base64 string. The encoded string is from a dataUri. It is

`<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA">text file</a>`

I'm trying to decode "//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA" which is supposed to give "foo bar" as output. When I click the anchor tag it downloads a file as expected with the same expected string "foo bar" in it.

If I use `atob('//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA')` I'm not getting the desired output

```js
var a=atob('//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA');
console.log(a);
```

I've even tried to give "utf8" as second arguement and no luck :(

How to extract the original encoded string from this dataUri? Thanks :)

Comment: This might help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: `btoa('foo bar')` gives me `"Zm9vIGJhcg=="`, then `atob("Zm9vIGJhcg==")` gives me `foo bar` are you sur about your base64 string ?

Comment: I'm trying to decode the base64 string in this dataUri:<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA">text file</a> I believe that 5m... is the correct according to what given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: `5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQBy‌` is not a Base64 version of `foo bar`; it is the Base64 version of `æ\`ðð` (+ SO trimmed some invalid chars); I'd argue that's more of an auth string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` isn't valid in the function `atob`: it will only take valid Base64 strings, which contain numbers,letters, and sometimes a `==`. Strip those first and then run it:

```
> atob('5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA') // console input
< "æ`ðð" // console output; SO stripped some chars
```

As @Guillaume Badi said in the comments, your Base64 string is *not* `foo bar`. To be honest, it looks more like an authentication key/tag, which usually aren't human readable anyways.

Comment: Okay but there must be some way to decode this...I'm getting the correct string in the downloaded file...